Unable to connect to Snowflake in .NET using key passphrase authentication technique
try
{
    string activeProfile = configuration["ActiveProfile"];
    string account = configuration[$"Snowflake:{activeProfile}:Account"];
    string user = configuration[$"Snowflake:{activeProfile}:User"];
    string database = configuration[$"Snowflake:{activeProfile}:Database"];
    string warehouse = configuration[$"Snowflake:{activeProfile}:Warehouse"];
    string schema = configuration[$"Snowflake:{activeProfile}:Schema"];
    string role = configuration[$"Snowflake:{activeProfile}:Role"];
    string privateKeyFilePath = "pathtoprivatekey"; // Path to your private key
    
    // Load proxy settings
    string proxyHosthttps = configuration[$"Snowflake:Proxy:HTTPS:Host"];
    string proxyPorthttps = configuration[$"Snowflake:Proxy:HTTPS:Port"];
    string proxyHosthttp = configuration[$"Snowflake:Proxy:HTTP:Host"];
    string proxyPorthttp = configuration[$"Snowflake:Proxy:HTTP:Port"];
    
    // Set environment variables for proxy
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("HTTP_PROXY", $"http://{proxyHosthttp}:{proxyPorthttp}");
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("HTTPS_PROXY", $"http://{proxyHosthttps}:{proxyPorthttps}");
    
    // Load the private key from the file and remove headers, footers, and line breaks
    string privateKeyText = File.ReadAllText(privateKeyFilePath)
        .Replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
        .Replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
        .Replace("\n", "")
        .Replace("\r", "")
        .Trim();  // Remove any extraneous whitespace
    
    // Reformat the private key with `\n` every 64 characters
    StringBuilder formattedPrivateKey = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < privateKeyText.Length; i += 64)
    {
        int chunkSize = Math.Min(64, privateKeyText.Length - i);
        formattedPrivateKey.Append(privateKeyText.Substring(i, chunkSize));
        formattedPrivateKey.Append("\\n");  // Add newline escape sequence for each 64-char chunk
    }
    
    // Handle trailing `=` signs (double any that are present)
    string privateKeyFinal = formattedPrivateKey.ToString();
    if (privateKeyFinal.EndsWith("="))
    {
        privateKeyFinal = privateKeyFinal.Replace("==", "====").Replace("=", "==");
    }
    privateKeyFinal = privateKeyFinal.TrimEnd('\\', 'n');  // Remove trailing \n
    
    // Create the connection string with key-pair authentication (no password here)
    var connectionString = $"scheme=https;account={account};user={user};db={database};schema={schema};role={role};warehouse={warehouse};authenticator=snowflake_jwt;PRIVATE_KEY={privateKeyFinal}";
    
    // Create the SnowflakeDbConnection object
    using (var _connection = new SnowflakeDbConnection { ConnectionString = connectionString })
    {
        // Open the connection
        _connection.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Successfully connected to Snowflake using key pair authentication.");
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Print the error message
    Console.WriteLine($"Failed to open connection: {ex.Message}\n{ex.StackTrace}");
}

Getting below error from above code:
Error Message :

Snowflake.Data.Client.SnowflakeDbException: 'Error: Could not read private key with value passed in connection string. \n Error : incorrect private key value or private key format: use "\n" for newlines and double the equals sign. SqlState: , VendorCode: 270052, QueryId: '

I have tried different ways to format the private key but nothing has worked for me.

I don't use .Net connector but I would expect it should work with private keys as other connectors such as ODBC and Python. My private key still has the BEGIN PRIVATE KEY and END PRIVATE KEY lines. And the last 2 characters of the private key are ==. It has lines of 64 characters each with \n line delimiters. I would not edit the key in the code. Set the key in the file path with proper formatting and use it as is.
